# Scraping Data from a Tableau Map

Tags: python, web-scraping, tableau-api, screen-scraping

I am trying to pull locations and names of Naloxone distribution centers in Illinois for a research project on the opioid crisis.

This tableau generated dashboard is accessible from here from the department of public health https://idph.illinois.gov/OpioidDataDashboard/

I've tried everything I could find. First changing the url to "download" the data using Tableau's interface. That only let me download a pdf map not the actual dataset behind it. Second, I modified the python script I've seen a few times on Stack overflow to try to request the data. But, I think it runs into some kind of error. Code below.

```
url = "https://interactive.data.illinois.gov/t/DPH/views/opioidTDWEB_prod/NaloxoneDistributionLocations"

r = requests.get(
    url,
    params= {
        ":embed":"y",
        ":showAppBanner":"false",
        ":showShareOptions":"true",
        ":display_count":"no",
        "showVizHome": "no"
    }
)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup)
tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)

dataUrl = f'https://tableau.ons.org.br{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'

r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})

dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

print(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"])
```

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Edit

I've made a [tableau scraper library](https://github.com/bertrandmartel/tableau-scraping) to extract the worksheets data into a pandas dataframe.

The code is simpler, but in your case you still need to build the URL with the xsrf token :

```py
from tableauscraper import TableauScraper as TS
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

init_url = "https://idph.illinois.gov/OpioidDataDashboard/"
r = requests.get(init_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
paramTags = dict([
    (t["name"], t["value"])
    for t in soup.find("div", {"class": "tableauPlaceholder"}).findAll("param")
])

url = f'{paramTags["host_url"]}trusted/{paramTags["ticket"]}{paramTags["site_root"]}/views/{paramTags["name"]}'

ts = TS()
ts.loads(url)
dashboard = ts.getWorkbook()

for t in dashboard.worksheets:
    # show worksheet name
    print(f"WORKSHEET NAME : {t.name}")
    # show dataframe for this worksheet
    print(t.data)
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://replit.com/@bertrandmartel/TableauIllinoisOpioId)

---

#### Original post

It's a bit complex since there are a combination of the following :

- the tableau "configuration page" where there is tsconfig textarea is not part of the original page. The url is built dynamically from some `param` html tag
- it uses a cross forgery token in cookies but in order to get that cookie you need to call a specific api whose url is built dynamically from some `param` html tag
- from the tsconfig parameter, we can build the data url as you've found out in other stackoverflow post such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62095206/how-to-scrape-a-public-tableau-dashboard/62106733#62106733), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64131666/scrape-data-from-tableau-public-dashboard/64148089#64148089) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61962611/how-can-i-scrape-tooltips-value-from-a-tableau-graph-embedded-in-a-webpage/61976399#61976399)

The flow is the following :

- call `GET https://idph.illinois.gov/OpioidDataDashboard/`, scrape the `param` tags under the div with class `tableauPlaceholder`

From there the host is : https://interactive.data.illinois.gov

- from the former `param` tags, build the "session URL" which looks like this :

  ```
  GET /trusted/{ticket}/t/DPH/views/opioidTDWEB_prod/MortalityandMorbidity
  ```

the url above will be only used to store the cookies (including xsrf token in the cookies)

- from the former `param` tags, build the "configuration URL" which looks like this :

  ```
  GET /t/DPH/views/opioidTDWEB_prod/MortalityandMorbidity
  ```

Extract the textarea with id `tsConfigContainer` and parse the json from it

- build the "data url" from the json extracted above, the url looks like this :

  ```
  POST /vizql/t/DPH/w/opioidTDWEB_prod/v/MortalityandMorbidity/bootstrapSession/sessions/{session_id}
  ```

Then you have a json response with some string in front of it to prevent [json hijacking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669766/2614364). You need regex to extract it and then parse the huge json data

All url needed would be like :

```
GET https://idph.illinois.gov/OpioidDataDashboard/
GET https://interactive.data.illinois.gov/trusted/yIm7jkXyRQuH9Ff1oPvz_w==:790xMcZuwmnvijXHg6ymRTrU/t/DPH/views/opioidTDWEB_prod/MortalityandMorbidity
GET https://interactive.data.illinois.gov/t/DPH/views/opioidTDWEB_prod/MortalityandMorbidity
POST https://interactive.data.illinois.gov/vizql/t/DPH/w/opioidTDWEB_prod/v/MortalityandMorbidity/bootstrapSession/sessions/2A3E3BA96A6C4E65B36AEDB4A536D09F-1:0
```

The full code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

s = requests.Session()

init_url = "https://idph.illinois.gov/OpioidDataDashboard/"
print(f"GET {init_url}")
r = s.get(init_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
paramTags = dict([
    (t["name"], t["value"]) 
    for t in soup.find("div", {"class":"tableauPlaceholder"}).findAll("param")
])

# get xsrf cookie
session_url = f'{paramTags["host_url"]}trusted/{paramTags["ticket"]}{paramTags["site_root"]}/views/{paramTags["name"]}'
print(f"GET {session_url}")
r = s.get(session_url)

config_url = f'{paramTags["host_url"][:-1]}{paramTags["site_root"]}/views/{paramTags["name"]}'
print(f"GET {config_url}")
r = s.get(config_url,
    params = {
        ":embed": "y",
        ":showVizHome": "no",
        ":host_url": "https://interactive.data.illinois.gov/",
        ":embed_code_version": 2,
        ":tabs": "yes",
        ":toolbar": "no",
        ":showShareOptions": "false",
        ":display_spinner": "no",
        ":loadOrderID": 0,
})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)

dataUrl = f'{paramTags["host_url"][:-1]}{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'
print(f"POST {dataUrl}")
r = s.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})
dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

print(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"])
```

[Try this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeCovidDataTableau)