# Scrape Data from Tableau Public dashboard

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tableau-api

I am very new to the world of scraping data off of websites and am at a lost on how to grab data off of a website that is using Tableau Public

website: https://showmestrong.mo.gov/data/public-health/

I've been reading up on several sources on how to inspect the elements and finding the table within it but I am at a loss. I've tried using in Python `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` but don't know how to work past that.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

r = requests.get("https://showmestrong.mo.gov/data/public-health/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
```

and it doesn't seem to show any tables about cases and deaths for example.

Any tips or documentation/forums about this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tableau.js library seems to load another url from which it gets the data :

https://public.tableau.com/views/COVID-19inMissouri/COVID-19inMissouri?:embed=y&:showVizHome=no&:host_url=https%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableau.com%2F&:embed_code_version=3&:tabs=no&:toolbar=no&:animate_transition=yes&:display_static_image=no&:display_spinner=no&:display_overlay=yes&:display_count=yes&:language=en&:loadOrderID=0

From there, it's very similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62106733/2614364) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61976399/2614364) where you would extract a JSON configuration from a `textarea` tag. Extract the `sessionid` to build the URL to get the data :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
import re

r = requests.get("https://public.tableau.com/views/COVID-19inMissouri/COVID-19inMissouri", 
    params = {
    ":embed": "y",
    ":showVizHome": "no",
    ":host_url": "https://public.tableau.com/",
    ":embed_code_version": 3,
    ":tabs": "no",
    ":toolbar": "no",
    ":animate_transition": "yes",
    ":display_static_image": "no",
    ":display_spinner": "no",
    ":display_overlay": "yes",
    ":display_count": "yes",
    ":language": "en",
    ":loadOrderID": 0
})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

tableauData = json.loads(soup.find("textarea",{"id": "tsConfigContainer"}).text)

dataUrl = f'https://public.tableau.com{tableauData["vizql_root"]}/bootstrapSession/sessions/{tableauData["sessionid"]}'

r = requests.post(dataUrl, data= {
    "sheet_id": tableauData["sheetId"],
})
dataReg = re.search('\d+;({.*})\d+;({.*})', r.text, re.MULTILINE)
info = json.loads(dataReg.group(1))
data = json.loads(dataReg.group(2))

print(data["secondaryInfo"]["presModelMap"]["dataDictionary"]["presModelHolder"]["genDataDictionaryPresModel"]["dataSegments"]["0"]["dataColumns"])
```

The result is not JSON so it needs to be parsed using regex to extract the JSON configuration from it as depicted in the above code

[run this on repl.it](https://repl.it/@bertrandmartel/ScrapeTableauMissouri)

Comment: Thank you so much!!! You've helped so much with this.
If I may ask, do you know how or any other forums that can help with parsing this huge line of data?